# Is =~ in Perl equivalent to re.match in Python?

Tags: python, regex, perl

I'm trying to replicate Perl Fathom in Python. This step corrects the syllable count for some word combinations. Is =~ equivalent to re.match in Python? re.match only looks for the first instance. Thank you!

```
 @SubSyl = (
           'cial',
           'tia',
           'cius',
           'cious',
           'giu',              
           'ion',
           'iou',
           'sia$',
           '.ely$',             
           '[^td]ed$',          
          );

 foreach (@SubSyl) {
          $syl-- if $word =~ /$_/;
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`=~` is the binding operator. It can bind a match, substitution, or transliteration. I guess only the first one could be equivalent to matching in Python, but it seems you need `re.search` instead, as matching with `//` is not anchored at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly not [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match). It's a bit of a gotcha, but `re.match` matches pattern only starting at the beginning of the string.

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

[`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) is more likely what you are looking for (unless you regex patter happens to always match beginning of the string).